# generate new list with two columns filtered and summed data

Tags: java, lambda

I have a list with two columns to filter, store and productType, and I need to generate a new list with consolidated amount_1 and amount_2.

```
    List<stock> allStock = new ArrayList<>();

    allStock.add(new stock("l1", "CAIXA", 1, 4));
    allStock.add(new stock("l1", "CABIDE", 1, 0));
    allStock.add(new stock("l1", "CAIXA", 5, 5));
    allStock.add(new stock("l1", "CABIDE", 1, 0));

    allStock.add(new stock("l2", "CAIXA", 1, 4));
    allStock.add(new stock("l2", "CABIDE", 1, 0));
    allStock.add(new stock("l2", "CAIXA", 5, 5));
    allStock.add(new stock("l2", "CABIDE", 1, 1));



public stock(String store, String productType, Integer amount_1, Integer amount_2);
```

I need a new list like:

l1, CAIXA , 6, 9

l1, CABIDE, 2, 0

l2, CAIXA,  6, 9

l2, CABIDE, 2, 1

Comment: If the answer work or not for you please inform in comment. it will help to improve myself. after all we all are here to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You can use, `Collectors.toMap` with streams with the `mergeFunction` explicitly defined in the `Stock` class as:

```
List<Stock> resultingStocks = new ArrayList<>(allStock
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(st -> 
                        Arrays.asList(st.getStore(), st.getProductType()), 
                Function.identity(), 
                this::mergeStocks)) // explicit merging behaviour
        .values());
```

where the `mergeStocks` is defined in the same class as :

```
Stock mergeStocks(Stock stock1, Stock stock2) {
    return new Stock(stock1.getStore(), stock1.getProductType(), stock1
            .getAmount_1() + stock2.getAmount_1(), stock1.getAmount_2() + stock2.getAmount_2());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package ClassConcept;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class stock {
    String s1,s2;
    int a1,a2;
    stock(String s1, String s2, int a1, int a2){
        this.s1 = s1;
        this.s2 = s2;
        this.a1 = a1;
        this.a2 = a2;

    }
}

public class ClassSpecifier {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<stock> allStock = new ArrayList<>();

        allStock.add(new stock("l1", "CAIXA", 1, 4));
        allStock.add(new stock("l1", "CABIDE", 1, 0));
        allStock.add(new stock("l1", "CAIXA", 5, 5));
        allStock.add(new stock("l1", "CABIDE", 1, 0));

        allStock.add(new stock("l2", "CAIXA", 1, 4));
        allStock.add(new stock("l2", "CABIDE", 1, 0));
        allStock.add(new stock("l2", "CAIXA", 5, 5));
        allStock.add(new stock("l2", "CABIDE", 1, 1));

       // create a new list
        List<stock> allStockNew = new ArrayList<>();

        // now yo have to add your logic of adding multiple stock in this. you can use while or any condition as per your need

    // iterate through new list. if element present, add new value in this. else enter new entry.
        for(int i = 0 ; i < allStockNew.size() ; i++) {

            if (allStockNew.get(i).s2.euqals( "CAIXA") && allStockNew.get(i).s1.euqals( "l1")) {// your new stock name
                stock s = allStockNew.get(i);
                s.a1+=5;//new value
                s.a2+=5; // new value
                allStockNew.add(s);
            }
            else {
                allStockNew.add(new stock("l1", "CABIDE", 1, 0));
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I have corrected the code. it will work. match your stock constructor with mine and you will understand variables as per your constructor. it will clear what are s1 s2 a1 and a2 are. I have already wrote a full working code. please check it properly and for any confusion comment here.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solition is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * @Author Jack <jackkobec>
 */
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Stock> allStock = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Stock> result = new ArrayList<>();

        allStock.add(new Stock("l1", "CAIXA", 1, 4));
        allStock.add(new Stock("l1", "CABIDE", 1, 0));
        allStock.add(new Stock("l1", "CAIXA", 5, 5));
        allStock.add(new Stock("l1", "CABIDE", 1, 0));

        allStock.add(new Stock("l2", "CAIXA", 1, 4));
        allStock.add(new Stock("l2", "CABIDE", 1, 0));
        allStock.add(new Stock("l2", "CAIXA", 5, 5));
        allStock.add(new Stock("l2", "CABIDE", 1, 1));

        allStock.stream().map(stock -> stock.productType).distinct()
                .forEach(distinctProductType -> {
                    allStock.stream().filter(stock -> stock.productType.equals(distinctProductType))
                            .reduce((stock1, stock2) -> {
                                if (stock1.store.equals(stock2.store)) {
                                    result.add(
                                            new Stock(
                                                    stock1.store,
                                                    stock1.productType,
                                                    stock1.amount_1 + stock2.amount_1,
                                                    stock1.amount_ + stock2.amount_));
                                }

                                return stock2;
                    });

                });

        result.forEach(stock -> System.out.println(
                "store: " + stock.store + "\n"
                + "productType: " + stock.productType + "\n"
                + "amount_1: " + stock.amount_1 + "\n"
                + "amount_: " + stock.amount_ + "\n"
        ));
    }
}

class Stock {
    public String store;
    public String productType;
    public Integer amount_1;
    public Integer amount_;

    public Stock() {
    }

    public Stock(String store, String productType, Integer amount_1, Integer amount_) {
        this.store = store;
        this.productType = productType;
        this.amount_1 = amount_1;
        this.amount_ = amount_;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Stock{" +
                "store='" + store + '\'' +
                ", productType='" + productType + '\'' +
                ", amount_1=" + amount_1 +
                ", amount_=" + amount_ +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Output:

> store: l1 productType: CAIXA amount_1: 6 amount_: 9
>
> store: l2 productType: CAIXA amount_1: 6 amount_: 9
>
> store: l1 productType: CABIDE amount_1: 2 amount_: 0
>
> store: l2 productType: CABIDE amount_1: 2 amount_: 1

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution.  I created a `Stock` class and used your provided names for the fields. This also helps make it easier to follow what was going on in the streams.  I also added a `toString` method to the class to display the values of each stock entry.  `Getters` would also be useful as then `method references` could be used in place of `lambdas` when retrieving values.  But I didn't know if your class had them.

Here is the lambda for the `reducing function`.  It creates a new stock and adds the values to it. I made it external to avoid cluttering the stream solution.  It could have been just as easily added to it.

```java
         BinaryOperator<Stock> op = (stock1, stock2) -> new Stock(stock2.store,
              stock2.productType, stock1.amount1 + stock2.amount1,
              stock1.amount2 + stock2.amount2);
```

1. First, group by store, then by product type.
2. Then reduce the contents of the final lists by adding together the values of 
   the same stock.
3. Then return just the list of the final stocks as requested.

```java
          List<Stock> list =
                allStock.stream()
                     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(stk -> stk.store,
                      Collectors.groupingBy(stk -> stk.productType,
                            Collectors.reducing(new Stock(),
                                  op)))).values().stream().flatMap(
                                        a -> a.values().stream()).collect(
                                              Collectors.toList());
         for (Stock s : list) {
            System.out.println(s);
         }
       }
    }
```

Here is the output.

```
 l1 CABIDE 2 0
 l1 CAIXA  6 9
 l2 CABIDE 2 1
 l2 CAIXA  6 9
```

Your modified stock class.

```java
    class Stock {
       String store, productType;
       int    amount1, amount2;

       public Stock() {
       }
       public Stock(String store, String productType, int amount1, int amount2) {
          this.store = store;
          this.productType = productType;
          this.amount1 = amount1;
          this.amount2 = amount2;
       }

       public String toString() {
          return store + " " + productType + " " + amount1 + " " + amount2;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want an unique stock list you can achieve it like this:

```
HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

allStock
  .stream()
  .forEach(s -> {
    if(myMap.get(s.store + s.productType) == null) {
      myMap.put(s.store + s.productType, s)
    } else {
      myMap.get(s.store + s.productType).amount_1 + s.amount_1;
      myMap.get(s.store + s.productType).amount_2 + s.amount_2;
    }
  });

return myMap.values(); //your list of stock
```

This part is important: `myMap.put(s.store + s.productType, s)`. The first parameter is your unique identifier, with which you can identify duplicates. With the second parameter you add the stock.

Comment: If it solves your question please accept my answer and/or upvote. Otherwise please add a comment.